# Python 3 module import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a python 3.4 file and trying to import some of the variables into another python script. Both of the scripts are in the same folder but I keep getting an error.

I can use the import and it works fine. However when I try to import variables from the script using from ServerConfiguration import port, ip I get an error saying NameError: name 'ServerConfiguration' is not defined

ServerConfiguration module:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

serverIP = None

def serverSocket():
    PORT = 8884 # Port the server is listening on

ServerEst = input('Has a server been established')
if ServerEst == 'yes':
    ServerIP = input ('Enter the servers IP address')
    socks = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    socks.bind((ServerIP, PORT))
    print('Connection  Established at ' + serverIP)
else:
    CreateServer = input('Would you like to create a server')
    if CreateServer == 'yes':
        ServerIP = input('What is you LAN IP? Please remeber if reomte user are allowed to connect port forward port "8884" ')
        socks = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        socks.bind((ServerIP, PORT))
        print('Connection  Established to ' + ServerIP)
    else:
        print ('Defaulting to default')
        ServerIP = 'localhost'
        socks = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        socks.bind((ServerIP, PORT))
        print('Connection  Established to ' + ServerIP)
```

UserModule:

```
    from ServerConfiguration import serverSocket, serverIP 
    import socket
    import sys
    import os

    def sendMessage():
        sockc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        while True:
              MESSAGE = input('Type the message to send ')
              sockc.sendto((MESSAGE.encode, "utf-8"), (serverIP, PORT))
              print(MESSAGE)


    ServerConfiguration.serverSocket()
    sendMessage()
```

Comment: Could you provide fragment of you source code with error?

Comment: I am currently running the user interface out of a windows console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
from ServerConfiguration import serverSocket, serverIP
```

you should write just

```
serverSocket()
```

without ServerConfiguration.

Another way:

```
import ServerConfiguration
...
ServerConfiguration.serverSocket()
```